# Unable to print the output, Path problem is coming

Tags: python

I am using Google co lab. # Error: SwissEph file 'se13681s.se1' not found in PATH '/usr/share/ephe/' is coming, how to overcome this problem.

```
pip install pyswisseph
import swisseph as swe
swe.set_ephe_path 
('/usr/share/ephe') 
# set path to ephemeris.    
files
jd = swe.julday(2008,3,21)
swe.calc_ut(jd, 
swe.AST_OFFSET+13681)[0][0] 
# asteroid Monty Python
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means that `swisseph` could not find the file `/usr/share/ephe/se13681s.se1`. Verify that the file exists.
Your code seems messed up, there is a command `pip install pyswisseph`, some Python code with strange styling (very short lines) and a strange word (`files`) in the middle.

Comment: pip install pyswisseph
import swisseph as swe
swe.set_ephe_path ('/usr/share/ephe') 
# set path to ephemeris files
jd = swe.julday(2008,3,21)
swe.calc_ut(jd, swe.AST_OFFSET+13681)[0][0] 
# asteroid Monty Python.                                     Library is correct.

Comment: file: /usr/share/ephe/se13681s.se1.                            How to check the file exists or not.